# How to implement a digital anti-aliasing filter?

Tags: python, scipy

I sampled a signal with a sampling rate of 1 MHz without applying an analog anti-aliasing filter. How can I implement a digital anti-aliasing filter in Python. To avoid the ValueError: "Digital filter critical frequencies must be 0 < Wn < 1" I set Wn to 0.99, which I understand means that frequencies above 0.99 * Nyquist frequency = 0.99 * 500 kHz = 495 kHz are cut off. Here is my implementation:

```
from scipy.signal import butter, sosfilt

sos = butter(5, 0.99, btype='low', output='sos', analog=False)
y = sosfilt(sos, data)
```

Can anyone please confirm that I am using it correctly.

Comment: If you've already sampled the signal, it's too late to apply an anti-aliasing filter.

Comment: Please show the exact and complete traceback of the error message.

Comment: I could avoid the error by setting Wn to 0.99. Is it not possible to implement an anti-aliasing filter digitally?

Comment: If you have solved the error I don't understand what your question is. No, you have to remove signal content above the nyquist frequency *before* sampling in order to avoid aliasing.

Comment: I was not sure whether this is a correct way to implement an anti-aliasing filter. Sadly, it's not. Thank you very much for your help